# How to store array of objects in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 radio buttons say `x`, `y` and `z`. On `click` on `x`, data is loaded and so on..

Now in localStorage, I want to set data for `x`, `y` and `z` differently  and get it.

Here, I'm giving a sample of the program.

Javascript:

```
var setInLocalStorage = function(){
    //on click of  x radio and getting data from model and called 
    // from one  function
    var x = {
        t = model.x.t;
        d = model.x.d;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('x' ,JSON.stringyfy(x));
}

var getFromLocalStorage = function() { 
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x'));
    //storing back to model
    model.x.t = obj.t;
    model.x.d = obj.d; 
    // populating data on screen which was stored in local storage
    $scope.x.t = model.x.t ;
    $scope.x.d = model.x.d;
}
```

How to store data of `y`and `z` and should display on screen on switching to radio button?

Comment: Try to use [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) instead `localStorage`

Comment: JSON.stringyfy ? should be JSON.stringify

Comment: why don't you use `angular services` for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. You have typo on your code and you don't need to set each property. Just set the `x` on scope.

```
var setInLocalStorage = function(){
    var x =  model.x
    localStorage.setItem('x', JSON.stringify(x));
}

var getFromLocalStorage = function() { 
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x'));
    model.x = obj;
    $scope.x = model.x;
}
```

But the best practice is not to do these type of actions in your controller. You should be using `angular.factory` or `angular.service` for this.

In your x-storage.js

```
angular.factory('xStorage', function(){
 var x = localStorage.getItem('x') || {};
 return {
  getX: function(){
    return x;
  },
  setX: function(xData){
    x = xData;
    localStorage.setItem('x', xData);
  }
 }
})
```

In your controller.js

```
angular.controller('controllerName', function(xStorage){
 $scope.x = xStorage.getX();

 $scope.clickButton = function(anyValue) {
   xStorage.setX(anyValue);
 }
})
```

Comment: This did'nt  worked when i clicked to other radio button i did not got saved data for that radio .

Comment: @PJ You should use it with angular.watch and set the value on change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setObject():

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CoolLocalStorage } from 'angular2-cool-storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
    localStorage: CoolLocalStorage;

    constructor(localStorage: CoolLocalStorage) {
        this.localStorage = localStorage;   
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.localStorage.setItem('itemKey', 'itemValue');

        console.log(this.localStorage.getItem('itemKey'));

        this.localStorage.setObject('itemKey', {
            someObject: 3
        });

        console.log(this.localStorage.getObject('itemKey'));
    }
}
```

For More details :

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cool-storage

Comment: Op is using AngularJS.